# Unable to properly import a library into Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm working on a obd2 scanner application. I need to import obd-java-api library from Github. In readme it says to include

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.pires:obd-java-api:1.0'
}
```

in the project's build.gradle. After doing that when I write a command from library I get a "Cannot resolve symbol" error. Am I doing something wrong? I never used additional libraries in Android Studio, so this is new to me.
Here is the piece of my code with the errors

```
new EchoOffObdCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), 
    socket.getOutputStream());
new LineFeedOffObdCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), 
    socket.getOutputStream());
new TimeoutObdCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), 
    socket.getOutputStream());
new SelectProtocolObdCommand(ObdProtocols.AUTO).run(socket.getInputStream(), 
    socket.getOutputStream());
```

Here is the gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aro.diagfix"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.pires:obd-java-api:1.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you post full app level build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got fixed. I need to write commands in try catch. After that I can import from github library!

```
try {
    new EchoOffCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
    new LineFeedOffCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
    new TimeoutCommand(125).run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
    new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.AUTO).run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
    new AmbientAirTemperatureCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Comment: in try you are not included EchoOffCommand . We should add EchoOffObdCommand right ?